# blue dot icon react google map

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I build simple web app for mobile browser react-google-maps.i am trying to show blue dot icon to indicate user current location. but it is not possible using react-google-maps. 
Can any one help to display blue dot icon on maps using react-google-map. is there way to change color blue to red?

```
 `     render() {
            <div>
            <MapWithAMarker markers={this}
            googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
            key=key&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
            loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100vh` }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
            />}</div> }

           const MapWithAMarker = compose(
           withScriptjs,
           withGoogleMap)(function(that) { 
           <GoogleMap
            center={{lat: parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lat), lng: 
            parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lng) }}
            defaultZoom={5}
            ref={map => (window.map = map)}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 
            parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lat), lng: 
            parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lng) }}
            ></GoogleMap>
           });
```

`

Comment: show your code  ..

Answer (score 0):

since javascript API doesn't provide currentLocation modules. But we do this using markers

```
<GoogleMap
        center={{lat: parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lat), lng: 
        parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lng) }}
        defaultZoom={5}
        ref={map => (window.map = map)}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: 
        parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lat), lng: 
        parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lng) }}
        >
 <Marker
        position={{ lat: 
        parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lat), lng: 
        parseFloat(props.currentLocation.lng) }}
        icon={{
          url: '/build/icon/yourIcon.svg',
        }}
      />
    )}

</GoogleMap>
```

Let me know if you need nay further assistance.